# The meaning of the symbol ~ on an array when that array is not a class

Tags: c++

I'm reading a C ++ code, the code has a line like this:

```
for(;;) 
{
    if(~theArray[i] & anotherCondition)
    {
        DoSomeThing();
    }
}
```

For some values i code goes back to the beginning of the loop, what exactly does this expression ~
on array, do?

Can anybody help?

Comment: It doesn't do anything on an array. `theArray[i]` is not an array, it's an array element.

Comment: Do not tag C for C++ questions.

Comment: This performs a bitwise NOT of the array element, then a bitwise AND of that with `anotherCondition`.

Comment: It does the same thing for array elements that it does for any other value.

Comment: `~` is a bitwise operator. In particular, `~` is a **not** operator, which negates the value.

Comment: `if(~theArray[i] & anotherCondition)` is equivalent to `int arrayElementValue = theArray[i]; if(~arrayElementValue & anotherCondition)` (assuming that `theArray` is an array of `int` elements).

Comment: @Shafa95 "negates" means something else

Comment: if you have some code that "goes back to the beginning of the loop" then it isnt the code you posted. Perhaps you simplified too much. The code you posted is an infinite loop

Comment: @Shafa95 Not "negation", but bitwise complement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`~` operator indicates bitwise complement.

Bitwise complement operator is an unary operator (works on only one operand). It changes 1 to 0 and 0 to 1.

For example:

> 35 = 00100011 (In Binary)
>
> complement of 35 is
>
> ~ 00100011 = 11011100 which is equal to 220 (In decimal)

Please check below resources to learn more about it

[Bitwise Operators](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/bitwise-operators#complement)

[Bitwise Complement Operator](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bitwise-complement-operator-tilde/)

Answer (score 0):

Sign '~' means negation, NOT. I guess if the array element is for example 00101001 in binary, then it will be changed to 11010110 for the operations inside 'if'.

Comment: A better term might be *bitwise complement* not negation.